# My C++ program won't compile on Visual Studio code

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-code, mingw-w64

I'm attempting to use Visual Studio Code for the first time and my C++ won't compile.

I have already added mingw's bin and bash.exe from MSYS2 to my PATH. All of my code is in the same directory and straight from microsoft's guide https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw (I did change the paths to mine). All of my files are also in the same directory.

I've included the file

helloworld.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout << "Hello World";
}
```

tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build hello world",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "-o",
                "helloworld",
                "helloworld.cpp"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\Mingw-w64\\mingw32\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceFolder}"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
     "configurations": [
         {
             "name": "(gdb) Launch",
             "type": "cppdbg",
             "request": "launch",
             "program": "${workspaceFolder}/helloworld.exe",
             "args": [],
             "stopAtEntry": true,
             "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
             "environment": [],
             "externalConsole": false,
             "MIMode": "gdb",
             "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\Mingw-w64\\mingw32\\bin\\gdb.exe",
             "setupCommands": [
                 {
                     "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                     "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                     "ignoreFailures": true
                 }
             ]
         }
     ]
 }
```

The file wouldn't build and I am continuously the same error message:

> g++.exe: error: helloworld.cpp: No such file or directory g++.exe:
>   fatal error: no input files compilation terminated. The terminal
>   process terminated with exit code: 1

---

Comment: The shown code is not valid C++. Your C++ compiler has no idea what "cout" is. You have not told your C++ what that's supposed to be, and the shown code is nowhere to be found at the link from the question. Try to actually compile the sample, proper C++ code that's given at the above link, verbatim, and see what happens.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The current code is valid, but the build commands aren't.

Comment: Oh I see because of the formatting the `#include <iostream>` was invisible in the original question. I fixed that.

Comment: So where did you install Mingw-w64? It seems the problem is that vscode can't find your compiler.

Comment: Is `helloworld.cpp` in the correct folder? To me it seems that `g++` can't find your source file by this output ***g++.exe: error: helloworld.cpp: No such file or directory***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like compiler isn't able to locate the source files , update the tasks.json to compile programs with complete path ,

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build hello world",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",//Just
                "-o",//edit
                "${workspaceFolder}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}"//these
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

here `${file}` gives complete path of the file with extension(.cpp) , `${workspaceFolder}` and `${fileBasenameNoExtension}` are pretty much self-explanatory too .

Comment: Your welcome , please accept and upvote this answer if you found it helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
 That eventually worked after I exited the shell and re-opened it

{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "echo",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "g++",
        "args": [
            "-g", "main.cpp"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }
]
}
```