# Can't build c++ in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

It seems like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57019588/my-c-program-wont-compile-on-visual-studio-code), except that I followed it and I still unable to make it work in VS Code. This is the directory that I use:

C:\Users\EKI\Desktop\projects_cpp

As the instructions goes, I put the .json files in \project_cpp.vscode and the .cpp file in \projects_cpp\helloworld.

My .cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout << "Hello World";
}
```

The .json files are in the following:

launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/helloworld.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": true,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
          {
            "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
            "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
            "ignoreFailures": true
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

settings.json

```
{
    "files.associations": {
        "ostream": "cpp"
    }
}
```

tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "label": "build hello world",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "g++",
        "args": [
          "-g",
          "${file}",
          "-o",
          "$${workspaceFolder}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
          ],
        "group": {
          "kind": "build",
          "isDefault": true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

c_cpp_properties.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

I tried turning off controlled folder access but still it doesn't work.

Here is the error message

> > Executing task: g++ -g c:\Users\EKI\Desktop\projects_cpp\helloworld\helloworld.cpp -o
> >     $C:\Users\EKI\Desktop\projects_cpp\helloworld <
>
> g++.exe: error: c:UsersEKIDesktopprojects_cpphelloworldhelloworld.cpp:
>   No such file or directory g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
>   compilation terminated. The terminal process terminated with exit
>   code: 1

Comment: C-Free Standard is an IDE without compiler. So, no, it's not possible. Did you install a compiler?

Comment: wait a minute, "C-Free Standard is an IDE without compiler."? Is this for real? I thought to myself that if it had a debugger, then it must have a compiler. Am I wrong these whole time?

Comment: For windows or Linux?  Linux should have one by default.  MS usually has free for download student versions of compilers.  GCC and Clang both also have completely free versions to download as well.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Windows. I've already acquired GCC and Clang from tutorials that I followed through VSCode Extensions and manual download, but I still can't get it to work.

Comment: Seeing bash appear with windows style paths is weird.  I don't have any further hints for you unfortunately.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to ask about the VSCode `.json`s which you don't understand? May be, the community could close the gap - making VSCode the working tool you are looking for.

Comment: @Scheff sounds good to me. I'll edit this question asap

Comment: It seems to me that you have an extra `$` before `${workspaceFolder}` in your tasks.json file.